# NuGet Uninstall.ps1 - remove a project reference

Tags: powershell, nuget

So in my Install.ps1 I can add a reference like this:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
$project.Object.References.Add("YourDLL")
```

How do you remove a project reference in PowerShell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some casting issues to do this in powershell.

this is the c# to remove a reference.

```
DTE dte = (DTE)dteObject;
        var targetProject = (VSProject)dte.GetProject(target).Object;
        var refToRemove = targetProject.References.Cast<Reference>().Where(assembly => assembly.Name.EndsWith(library, System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (refToRemove != null)
        {
            refToRemove.Remove();
        }
```

If you want to use the Solution Factory nuget package you can use the powershell command that solution factory adds.

```
Remove-LibraryReference  projectName system.web
```

Here is a link the the solution factory source http://solutionfactory.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/Forks/erichexter/PowershellRewrite

**Update:** new url for solution factory:
https://github.com/erichexter/SolutionFactory

Answer (score 14):

Here's what we use for [Machine.Specifications](http://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/blob/master/install.ps1):

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
$project.Object.References | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'Machine.Specifications.TDNetRunner' } | ForEach-Object { $_.Remove() }
```